# Protobuf-net: which nuget version corresponds to which git commit?

Tags: nuget, protobuf-net

Does anyone know how to figure out which commit in git corresponds to which Nuget version for Protobuf-net?

I use the Nuget version (2.0.0.668), but I have an error in my graph, and there is no good debug information without the source, so I would like to get a hint as to where the problem lies in my code.

The nuget package versions do not seem to be tagged in the repo I am using- 
https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net.git

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is really a stackoverflow question, but: [I've added some tags to the git repo](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/releases); however, the only interesting ones at the moment are `r668` (aka 2.0.0.668) and `v2.1.0-alpha-1` (the alpha core-clr release). I did not attempt to go back through all releases.